# Corrupted Module in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I sometimes run across this in node and it eventually gets fixed by fiddling with it without really understanding the root cause. here is what happens:

i require a module in multiple places in my code an the first few tend to work just fine. then somehow something corrupts the module where it just returns an empty object;

```
var m1 = require('./m1'); // returns just fine
.... /// somewhere latter in the code
var m1 = require('./m1'); // returns empty object
```

So I guess my question is, What would corrupt a module and how could you put some sort of assert debugger to catch it when it happens?

thanks

Comment: What does the `m1`module return as its exports?  It is possible that the module could be using globals that get trounced.

Comment: sometimes new Object() and sometimes the prototype of the original object. it doesnt use Global for anything. I thought at one point it maybe bc the object is a singleton but the instance i'm dealing with now ends with module.exports = new MyClass();

Comment: note: whats also odd is that it doesnt even show up in the module.children[] when all other requires do.  http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_loaded

Comment: it shows up in module.parent and the loaded property is false

Comment: I'm leaning now leaning towards a possible circular reference... (sorry for all the small comments)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. after long length of tracing it seems (at least for this instance) to be a circular reference issue.

Would have hoped to get an error but apparently it doesnt. thank you jfriend00 for helping out